# What would happen if earth ground and the PCB ground came into contact?

Tags: power-supply, circuit-analysis, pcb, ground, usb-device

So I have an ATX PSU that I'm converting into a 12v, 5v power supply. I also have a group of 4 USB ports from an old computer that I connected to the 5v line of the ATX PSU. Unfortunately, the USB casing is connected to the common ground (of the PCB) and the casing of the ATX is close to touching it and I was wondering what would happen if the common ground of the PCB came into contact with the metal ATX casing, which is connected to Earth.

Comment: On most PCs the ground of the PCB is directly connected to the chassis. Usually by lots of screws.

Comment: what will happen? nothing, other than slightly lower noise. it supposed to be that way unless you remove the earth to allow putting PSUs in series.

Comment: why don't you start by measuring the voltage between earth ground and PCB ground

Comment: Since the gnd/0V of the psu is normallly connected to earth this can present the issue of a dangerous sutuation occurring if you slip with a scope probe or mis-wire or any of the potential mistakes that occur when experimenting. When this happens you’ll  find out quickly that the high current output of the ATX supply can melt things. Ensure you have fuses or other protection on the power wiring. Realistically for most projects, anything over 1A is not required. Having in excess of that means mistakes are going to be more destructive.  I’d suggest not using an ATX supply as a bench supply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ATX supply ground, i.e. the black wires, are internally connected to the ATX supply metal chassis, which is also connected to mains earth/ground.

Nothing will happen, as they are already connected.

Comment: if they might touch then it might be a good idea to deliberately connect them. Better to have a reliable connection, than to have things randomly connecting and disconnecting even if it theoretically isn't a problem.